# Why does Nero 10 Essentials installer not recognize Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, installation, nero

When installing Nero Suite 10 Essentials that came with my ASUS IDE DVD Writer on the Win7 x64 box, the installer prompts for the following items as a precondition to complete installation

- Microsoft VC Redist 2005 KB973544 (x86)
- Microsoft VC Redist 2008 SP1 (x86)
- Microsoft VC Redist 2008 KB973522 (x86)
- Direct3D 9 Extensions 9.12.589.0
- Direct3D 9 Extensions 9.19.949.46
- Direct3D 9 Extensions 9.12.949.1104
- Direct3D 9 Extensions 9.24.950.2656
- Reboot Validator

After accepting the precondition - the installer brought up a dialog with the message - "Nero requires that your computer is running Windows XP with at least SP3, Windows Vista with at least SP1 or Windows 7".

Upon OK-ing this message, another dialog (Yes/No) came up. This one said - "The installation of  System Requirement Validator has failed. Setup will now exit."

I'm flummoxed. Why does the installer not recognize my Win 7 installation?

Comment: What about ImgBurn? Why do you need Nero? (Just a comment, not an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to run the installer in compatibility mode.

Comment: No can do. Even trying the various compatibility modes, the installer kept coming up with this message - "Nero requires that your computer is running Windows XP with at least SP3, Windows Vista with at least SP1 or Windows 7"

Comment: Ok, what _eventually_ worked was as follows
- Set compatibility mode to Vista SP2
- Reboot (i thought MS' penchant for reboots was solved!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternative to Nero. I recommend [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) for easily installing free software and freeware alternatives to traditional software.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it now. First download and install Windows installer 4.5. Pick from the list the one for your system. Below is the link.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8483

Then, Run the downloaded Nero 10 installer until the extraction process is complete. 
Click the Cancel button to abort the installation. 
Open your temp directory by entering %temp% into the address field of the Windows Explorer. 
Navigate to the extracted Nero folder NeroInstallFiles\Nero20100x (x for version). 
Open this folder and execute the file Nero.MultimediaSuite.MSI. 
Nero 10 should now get installed on your system.

This worked for me. Later